# Request a Quote for normal customer - Magento 2.2.2 EE

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.2.2, magento2-enterprise, b2b

Recently I installed **B2B** extension on **Magento 2.2.2 EE**. **Request quote** features only available on **company account**.

is it possible normal customer send request quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No Request a quote feature of Magento 2 EE B2B is only available for company account user.**

> **A company user/Business Account owner who want to purchased a huge**
>   **amount of bulk products can do negotiation on price of products so**
>   **its only available for company user(B2B Users)**

**For more details refer this link** -
 http://docs.magento.com/m2/b2b/user_guide/sales/quote-request.html

**But there are few extensions available which do same functionality for general customers as well . below are the reference link of those  extensions.**

https://www.fmeextensions.com/request-for-quote-magento-2.html

https://store.webkul.com/Quote-System-For-Magento2.html